# How to get the previous post in order of the numeric custom field number?

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to get the previous two posts before the current post in order of the custom field number that I created.

```
$previous_posts = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',                     
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'post__not_in' => array($current_post->ID, $next_post_id),
    'meta_key' => 'ereignis_jahr',
    'meta_type' => 'numeric',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
      'meta_query' => array(
      'before' => $current_post->meta_value_num
    )
  ));
```

I think the meta_query is the problem.
Appreciate any help.

Also> I tried to sort by date and post_date but the dates used exceed php limits of 1900?

Comment: I can only see the documentation mention `before` as a valid operator in a date query, not in meta queries. You need to provide a `compare` property, with an appropriate operator value.